# Can't seem to get an output and I do not know why

Tags: perl

I have a perl code that basically opens up a file, read it and then print it but for some reason, when I run it, I can't seem to get any output nor any error and I don't know why.

Here's my code:

```
#!usr/bin/perl

$syslogFile = '/Home/osboxes/Documents/syslog';
open(INFO, $syslogFile);
@lines = <INFO>;
close(INFO);
print @lines;
```

Comment: That shouldn't stop it working - itdefaults to read.

Comment: `open() or die $!` should tell you something... Also, `use strict` and `use warnings` would be useful.

Comment: @Sobrique hmm interesting, I didn't know that. I assume there is an error then that `or die "$!"` would reveal.

Comment: check your path to the file

Answer (score 4):

And this is why you need do two things:

- enable `use strict;` `use warnings;` at the start of your code.
- Check return codes from `open`.

I would also suggest that 3 arg open is greatly preferred to using a default:

```
open ( my $input, '<', $syslogfile ) or die $!;
```

And lastly - double check that file contains what you expect it to. E.g. it isn't empty.

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $syslogFile = '/Home/osboxes/Documents/syslog';
open(my $info, '<', $syslogFile) or die $!; 
my @lines = <$info>;
close($info) or warn $!;
print @lines;
```

I suspect it will tell you either "No such file or directory" or "permission denied".

Comment: Yes, it does say no such file or directory, no idea why though

Comment: I'm going to take a guess at the file not existing. But it could be an incorrect spelling (or case)

Comment: I dragged the file into the terminal to make sure and I got a file path of /home/osboxes/Documents/syslog', still same error but now it includes readline() on unopened file handle at the line "open(my $info, '<', $syslogFile) or die $!; "

Comment: @DBaculio Filesystems on *nix (which I assume you're using based on the shebang in your script) are almost always case sensitive. `/home/osboxes/Documents/syslog` is not the same as `/Home/osboxes/Documents/syslog`.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot sorry forgot to mention that I have tried both home and Home and both gave me the same error. Also tried out using sudo and seems like syslog file is the problem for me, I'm trying to work out how to open the file right now.

Comment: I got it to work now thanks. I just had a random dot on my $syslogFile on line 13 which gave the error! Well....this is embarassing...But anyway, thanks guys!

Comment: None the less. A valuable lesson in checking return codes.